# Can't paginate data in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, pagination

I've successfully retrieved data and displayed it in the list of table but my list is not having paginate

I tried to display 15 data per page,but it displayed all data at once in the page.My data is coming from API .

[image]

My controller

```
 public function index()
    {


        $response =  $this->client->get('getUserIndex')->getBody();
        $content = json_decode($response->getContents(),true);

        $collection = new \Illuminate\Support\Collection($content);

        $total = count($collection['data']);

        $paginationRecord = CollectionPaginate::paginate($collection, $total, 15);


         return view('configuration.comuserprofiles.ComUserProfilesList', compact('paginationRecord'));
}
```

half of my table view

```
   @foreach($paginationRecord as $i=>$user)

                            @foreach($user as $i => $u)

                             @php

                                $currentRecordno = 1;
                           // dd($u['irel__com_access_level']['ID']);
                            @endphp  

                            <tr>


                                <td>{{ $currentRecordno + $i }}</td>
                                 <td>{{ $u['ID'] }}</td>
                             <td>{{ $u['NICK_NAME'] }}</td>
                             <td>{{ $u['PWD_INVALID_HIT'] }}</td>

                         </tr>
                         @endforeach
```

my pagination blade

```
<div class="row row-pagination">
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
        <small class="text-muted inline m-t-sm m-b-sm"><font color="#00000f">{{ $paginationRecord->total() }} record/s found </font></small> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 text-right text-center-xs">
        <ul>
            {{ $paginationRecord->links() }}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm expecting to display 15 records per page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved already by adding ['data'] at $content in controller

```
$content = $content['data'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `take()` Collection's method to get specific number of elements

```php
$paginationRecord = CollectionPaginate::paginate($collection->take(15), $total, 15);
```

You can also use `forPage()`.

```php
$page = Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1;
$paginationRecord = new Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator($collection->forPage($page, 15), $total, 15, $page);
```

Comment: @adaminho which one did not work, and what did you get ?